# Center nav bar title with right and left bar items?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to set a navigation bar title but every approach i've tried so far either moves the title too far right or the view does not load at all and crashes the app. This is my latest attempt (app crashes)

```
    let rightItemSize = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.width
    let leftItemSize = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.width

    let navWidth = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width
    let navHeight = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height


    let titleWidth = navWidth! - (rightItemSize! + leftItemSize!)

    let requiredPadding = rightItemSize! - leftItemSize!

    var titleViewToAdd = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, titleWidth, navHeight!))
    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(requiredPadding, 0, titleWidth - requiredPadding, navHeight!))

    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14.0)
    label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    label.text = "\(albumsArtist)"

    titleViewToAdd.addSubview(label)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleViewToAdd
```

If i use self.navigationItem.title = "\(albumsArtist)". The text is centered and works great but eventually i'd like to have two lines of text and this method wouldn't work.

I am aware there are similar questions with answers on here but all the one's i have looked at have been for Objective-C and have not worked so well when i've tried to convert them to Swift.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to make it work with this!

```
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: 50, height: 40))
    label.backgroundColor = .red
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)

    label.text = "My title"
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    label.textColor = .black
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.textAlignment = .center

    self.navigationItem.titleView = label
```